# Python Logging with Multiprocessing in Windows

Tags: python, windows, logging, multiprocessing, python-logging

I have a rather large Python project which currently runs on Linux but I am trying to expand to Windows. I've reduced the code to a full example which can be run to illustrate my problems: I have two classes, Parent and Child. Parent is initialized first, creates a logger, and spawns a Child to do work:

```
import logging
import logging.config
import multiprocessing

class Parent( object ):
    def __init__(self, logconfig):
        logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    def spawnChild(self):
        self.logger.info('One')
        c = Child(self.logger)
        c.start()

class Child(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, logger):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.logger = logger

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Two')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Parent({
            'version':1, 
            "handlers": {
                "console": {
                    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
                    "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
                },
            },
            "root": {
                "level": "DEBUG",
                "handlers": [
                    "console",
                    ]
                }
            }
        )
    p.spawnChild()
```

On linux (specifically, ubuntu 12.04), I get the following (expected) output:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ python test.py 
One
Two
```

But, on Windows (specifically, Windows 7), it fails with a pickling error:

```
C:\>python test.py
<snip>
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: it's not found as thread.lock
```

The problem comes down to Windows' lack of a true fork, so objects have to be pickled when sent between threads. But, the logger can't be pickled. I've tried using `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to avoid pickling, and reference by name in Child:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    d = self.__dict__.copy()
    if 'logger' in d.keys():
        d['logger'] = d['logger'].name
    return d

def __setstate__(self, d):
    if 'logger' in d.keys():
        d['logger'] = logging.getLogger(d['logger'])
    self.__dict__.update(d)
```

This works in Linux just as before, and now Windows won't fail with the `PicklingError`. However, my output is only from Parent:

```
C:\>python test.py
One

C:\>
```

It seems that the child is unable to use the logger, despite no message complaining `No logger could be found for handler '__main__'` or any other error message. I've looked around and there are means by which I could completely restructure how I log in my program, but that's obviously a last resort. I'm hoping that I'm just missing something obvious, and that the wisdom of the crowd can point it out to me.

Comment: `if key in some_dict.keys()` is exactly the *wrong* way of performing that check. It takes O(n) time in python2. Just use `if key in some_dict`.  Regarding your problem. The subprocess may have a different stdout and hence you don't see the output. Try to add a file handler and check whether the output in file is correct or not.

Comment: Appreciate the note about the key, that was just copied from another SO post for testing.

All my actual logging is done in files, and the problem still occurs. The stdout was just easier to test with for creating the above script. Using 
                "multi_file_handler": {
                    "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
                    "filename": "output.log"
                },
leads to the same problem - "One\nTwo" on linux, "One" on windows

Comment: The problem might be that, when unpickling `__init__` is usually *not* invoked. Which means that the subprocess did *not* call `logging.config.dictConfig(...)` and hence it may be using the default configuration. Try to change the `__setstate__` method so that it calls `dictConfig` with the right settings and see if something changes.

Comment: That got the test code above to work, though I haven't gotten it to work in the larger project yet. It's definitely progress, I'll continue working and close this once I have the true solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, `Logger` objects are not picklable, because they use unpicklable `theading.Lock` and/or `file` objects internally. Your attempted workaround does avoid pickling the `logger`, but it ends up creating a completely different `Logger` in the child process, which happens to have the same name as the `Logger` in the parent; the effects of `logging.config` call you made are lost. To get the behavior you want you'll need to need to recreate the logger in the child process *and* re-call `logging.config.dictConfig`:

```
class Parent( object ):
    def __init__(self, logconfig):
        self.logconfig = logconfig
        logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def spawnChild(self):
        self.logger.info('One')
        c = Child(self.logconfig)
        c.start()

class Child(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, logconfig):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.logconfig = logconfig

    def run(self):
        # Recreate the logger in the child
        logging.config.dictConfig(self.logconfig)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        self.logger.info('Two')
```

Or, if you want to keep using `__getstate__`/`__setstate__`:

```
class Parent( object ):
    def __init__(self, logconfig):
        logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logconfig = logconfig

    def spawnChild(self):
        self.logger.info('One')
        c = Child(self.logger, self.logconfig)
        c.start()

class Child(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, logger, logconfig):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.logger = logger
        self.logconfig = logconfig

    def run(self):
        self.logger.info('Two')

    def __getstate__(self):
        d = self.__dict__.copy()
        if 'logger' in d:
            d['logger'] = d['logger'].name
        return d

    def __setstate__(self, d):
        if 'logger' in d:
            logging.config.dictConfig(d['logconfig'])
            d['logger'] = logging.getLogger(d['logger'])
        self.__dict__.update(d)
```

Comment: This is similar to @Bakuriu's comment above, though he also pointed out unpickling doesn't call to \__init__ which is why my placing of logging.config.dictConfig(self.logconfig) in \__init__ failed to work. It's not working in my actual project, but working in my test code. I'll continue tweaking and close this if I can find the solution from here.

Comment: @user2093082 Hmm, I don't see anywhere in your question or the comments where you said you put the call to `logging.config.dictConfig` in the `__init__` of `Child`. Am I missing something, or did you try that without actually explicitly mentioning it here?

Comment: I didn't say so explicitly, I tested it first in response to comments from Bakuriu

Comment: Between this answer and Bakuriu's comments I got everything to work.