# python multiprocessing - sending child process logging to GUI running in parent

Tags: python, multithreading, logging, multiprocessing, pyside2

I'm building an interface on top of some analysis code I've written that executes some SQL and processes the query results. There's logging surrounding a number of the events in this analysis code that I would like to expose to the user. Because the analysis code is rather long-running, and because I don't want the UI to block, thus far I've done this through putting the analysis function in to its own thread.

Simplified example of what I have now (complete script):

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets

def long_task():
    logging.info('Starting long task')
    time.sleep(3) # this would be replaced with a real task
    logging.info('Long task complete')

class LogEmitter(QtCore.QObject):
    sigLog = QtCore.Signal(str)

class LogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.emitter = LogEmitter()
    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.emitter.sigLog.emit(msg)

class LogDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        log_txt = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        log_txt.setReadOnly(True)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(log_txt)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event Log')
        handler = LogHandler()
        handler.emitter.sigLog.connect(log_txt.appendPlainText)
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    results = QtCore.Signal(object)

    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        results = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.results.emit(results)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        layout.addWidget(start_btn)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.log_dialog = LogDialog()
        self.worker = None

    def start(self):
        if not self.worker:
            self.log_dialog.show()
            logging.info('Run Starting')
            self.worker = Worker(long_task)
            self.worker.results.connect(self.handle_result)
            self.worker.start()

    def handle_result(self, result=None):
        logging.info('Result received')
        self.worker = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works fine, except that I need to be able to allow the user to stop the execution of the analysis code. Everything I've read indicates that there is no way to interrupt threads nicely, so using the `multiprocessing` library seems to be the way to go (there's no way to re-write the analysis code to allow for periodic polling, since the majority of time is spent just waiting for the queries to return results). It's easy enough to get the same functionality in terms of executing the analysis code in a way that doesn't block the UI by using `multiprocessing.Pool` and `apply_async`.

E.g. replacing `MainWindow` from above with:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        layout.addWidget(start_btn)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.log_dialog = LogDialog()
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.log_dialog.show()
            logging.info('Run Starting')
            self.pool.apply_async(long_task, callback=self.handle_result)

    def handle_result(self, result=None):
        logging.info('Result received')
        self.running = False
```

But I can't seem to figure out how I would go about retrieving the logging output from the child process and passing it to the parent to update the log dialog. I've read through just about every SO question on this as well as the cookbook examples of how to handle writing to a single log file from multiple processes, but I can't wrap my head around how to adapt those ideas to what I'm trying to do here.

### Edit

So trying to figure out what might be going on for why I'm seeing different behavior than @eyllanesc I added:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
print(f'In Func: {logger} at {id(logger)}')
```

and

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
print(f'In Main: {logger} at {id(logger)}')
```

to `long_task` and `Mainwindow.start`, respectively. When I run `main.py` I get:

```
In Main: <RootLogger root (INFO)> at 2716746681984
In Func: <RootLogger root (WARNING)> at 1918342302352
```

which seems to be what was described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724643/python-logging-with-multiprocessing-root-logger-different-in-windows)

This idea of using a `Queue` and `QueueHandler` though as a solution seems similar to @eyllanesc's original solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signals do not transmit data between processes, so for this case a Pipe must be used and then emit the signal:

```
# other imports
import threading
# ...

class LogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.r, self.w = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self.emitter = LogEmitter()
        threading.Thread(target=self.listen, daemon=True).start()

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.w.send(msg)

    def listen(self):
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.r.recv()
                self.emitter.sigLog.emit(msg)
            except EOFError:
                break

# ...
```

Comment: I'm still missing something here. How does logging data from the child process enter the pipe? When creating the child process, do I need to provide it the worker end of the pipe (in which case, I'm still not sure exactly clear on how I would set up the target function in the child process)? Just dropping this in to the code I currently have produces the same behavior (i.e. parent process is logged as expected, child logging doesn't end up in the parent though).

Comment: @user3014097 How strange, I have tried it and it works correctly, are you using my code in the code of your question or in another personalized code?

Comment: @user3014097 in the following link you will find my test code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/72a67e76350691012580f2207f1dd12b , try it and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Hmm...yeah running your main.py I see the same behavior I'm seeing in my script (i.e. only the parent is logged to the dialog). This is being run on Windows, does the issue explained here still apply?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167873/python-logging-with-multiprocessing-in-windows

Comment: @user3014097 I have tested it on Linux with PySide2 5.11 and Python 3.7 and it works correctly as shown in the image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4896200/48495203-7aee9b80-e7fd-11e8-8d15-0f529f517762.png

Comment: @user3014097 the link problem refers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167873/python-logging-with-multiprocessing-in-windows to something else.

Comment: Just to be sure I set up an environment with the same version of PySide and python, but I'm still seeing different behavior: https://imgur.com/a/fCyBbot

Comment: So, I'm seeing the same behavior as described here (see my edit):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724643/python-logging-with-multiprocessing-root-logger-different-in-windows

But isn't the prescribed fix more or less what your code is doing?

Comment: @user3014097 yes, I think that unwanted behavior is dependent on the platform

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered since your solution obviously works. I'm still not sure how to get this working on Windows given the platform limitations, but at least this is a place to start

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wanders in to this down the road, using `QueueHandler` and `QueueListener` leads to a solution that works on Windows as well. Borrowed heavily from [this answer to a similar question:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964369/3014097)

```
import logging
import sys
import time
import multiprocessing
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore

def long_task():
    logging.info('Starting long task')
    time.sleep(3) # this would be replaced with a real task
    logging.info('Long task complete')

def worker_init(q):
    qh = QueueHandler(q)
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(qh)

class LogEmitter(QtCore.QObject):
    sigLog = QtCore.Signal(str)

class LogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.emitter = LogEmitter()
    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        self.emitter.sigLog.emit(msg)

class LogDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.log_txt = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.log_txt.setReadOnly(True)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.log_txt)
        self.setWindowTitle('Event Log')

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(widget)
        start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        start_btn.clicked.connect(self.start)
        layout.addWidget(start_btn)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.log_dialog = LogDialog()
        self.running = False

        # sets up handler that will be used by QueueListener
        # which will update the LogDialoag
        handler = LogHandler()
        handler.emitter.sigLog.connect(self.log_dialog.log_txt.appendPlainText)

        self.q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        self.ql = QueueListener(self.q, handler)
        self.ql.start()

        # main process should also log to a QueueHandler
        self.main_log = logging.getLogger('main')
        self.main_log.propagate = False
        self.main_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.main_log.addHandler(QueueHandler(self.q))

        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1, worker_init, [self.q])

    def start(self):
        if not self.running:
            self.log_dialog.show()
            self.main_log.info('Run Starting')
            self.pool.apply_async(long_task, callback=self.handle_result)

    def handle_result(self, result=None):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.main_log.info('Result received')
        self.running = False

    def closeEvent(self, _):
        self.ql.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```