# Python Multiprocessing, Pytest, and Windows: How to perform pytest live-logging when using multiprocessing in a cross-platform setting?

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing, pytest

I created a [Github repo](https://github.com/edavalosanaya/SOQuestion) with all the code necessary to test the issue. For the sake of consistency and ease of search, I pasted most of the repo's `README.md` below.

> NOTE: This question requires Linux or a system that can (preferably a combination of Windows+Linux) support "spawn" and "fork" multiprocessing contexts.

### Setup Environment

Install the required packages through the following:

```bash
pip install logger_tt loguru pytest
```

My testing environment is the following:

- Python 3.9
- Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11

### Requirements

I am trying to make live logging with the `pytest` framework work with multiprocessing. The solution requires to function in Windows, MacOS and Linux operating systems. When developing multiprocessing, it is important considering the start process method, these are the available methods for each OS according to this [reference](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-start-method/):

- Windows: `spawn`
- MacOS: `spawn`, `fork`, `forkserver` (only `spawn` is stable, therby default)
- Linux: `spawn`, `fork`, `forkserver` (default `spawn`)

Avoid (if possible) using queues, servers, and custom pytest hooks.

Logs should go to the stdout or be visible in the terminal.

### Resources

Below is a collection of

- Looked At Websites

  - [Multiprocessing logging in Python](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-logging-in-python/)
  - [SO: Python Logging with Multiprocessing in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167873/python-logging-with-multiprocessing-in-windows)
  - [multiprocessing-logging library, only for POSIX](https://pypi.org/project/multiprocessing-logging/)
  - [SO: Python Multiprocessing returning results within Logging and running frozen on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64335940/python-multiprocessing-returning-results-with-logging-and-running-frozen-on-wind)
- Relevent Library Documentations Pages

  - [Logger_tt](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt#7-logging-in-multiprocessing)
  - [Loguru](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

    - [Pytest + Loguru](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resources/migration.html#making-things-work-with-pytest-and-caplog)
    - [Multiprocessing + Loguru](https://loguru.readthedocs.io/en/stable/resources/recipes.html#compatibility-with-multiprocessing-using-enqueue-argument)
  - [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/logging.html)

### The Test

First, I tried to see if three logging libraries (built-in `logging`, `logger_tt`, and `loguru`) worked with just multiprocessing, as done in `mp_logging.py`. In that file, there are 2 parameters `START_METHOD` and `LOGGING_METHOD`.

After getting the 3 libraries to work with both `fork` and `spawn` process starting methods, I tried to replicate the test within the `pytest` framework. I was not able to capture the children logging with any library when using `spawn`. Given that Windows can only use `spawn`, this is not a solution.

### Expected Output

Built-in Logging (both `spawn` and `fork`)

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ python mp_logging.py
2022-10-30 23:07:15,019 [INFO] test: Parent logging
2022-10-30 23:07:15,084 [INFO] test: Children Logging
2022-10-30 23:07:15,086 [INFO] test: Children Logging
2022-10-30 23:07:15,087 [INFO] test: Children Logging
2022-10-30 23:07:15,095 [INFO] test: Parent logging: end
```

logger_tt (`spawn`)

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ python mp_logging.py
[2022-10-30 23:08:36] INFO: Parent logging
[2022-10-30 23:08:36] INFO: SpawnProcess-1 Children Logging
[2022-10-30 23:08:36] INFO: SpawnProcess-2 Children Logging
[2022-10-30 23:08:36] INFO: SpawnProcess-3 Children Logging
[2022-10-30 23:08:36] INFO: Parent logging: end
```

logger_tt (`fork`)

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ python mp_logging.py
[2022-10-30 23:09:42] INFO: Parent logging
[2022-10-30 23:09:42] INFO: SpawnProcess-1 Children Logging
[2022-10-30 23:09:42] INFO: SpawnProcess-2 Children Logging
[2022-10-30 23:09:42] INFO: SpawnProcess-3 Children Logging
[2022-10-30 23:09:42] INFO: Parent logging: end
```

loguru (both `spawn` and `fork`)

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ python mp_logging.py
2022-10-30 23:11:07.608 | INFO     | __main__:<module>:92 - Parent logging
2022-10-30 23:11:07.712 | INFO     | __mp_main__:target_function:83 - Children Logging
2022-10-30 23:11:07.713 | INFO     | __mp_main__:target_function:83 - Children Logging
2022-10-30 23:11:07.715 | INFO     | __mp_main__:target_function:83 - Children Logging
2022-10-30 23:11:07.731 | INFO     | __main__:<module>:103 - Parent logging: end
```

### Actual Output

`logging` and `logger_tt` on `fork`: Correct output

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ pytest
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/eduardo/GitHub/SOQuestion, configfile: pyproject.toml
collected 1 item                                                                                    

test/test_logging.py::test_logging_with_multiprocessing 
------------------------------------------- live log call -------------------------------------------
Parent logging
Children Logging
Children Logging
Children Logging
Parent logging: end
PASSED                                                                                        [100%]

========================================= 1 passed in 0.02s =========================================
```

`logging` and `logger_tt` on `spawn`: Missing children output

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ pytest
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/eduardo/GitHub/SOQuestion, configfile: pyproject.toml
collected 1 item                                                                                    

test/test_logging.py::test_logging_with_multiprocessing 
------------------------------------------- live log call -------------------------------------------
Parent logging
Parent logging: end
PASSED                                                                                        [100%]

========================================= 1 passed in 0.26s =========================================
```

`loguru` for both `spawn` and `fork`: no output

```bash
(test) eduardo@avocado-XPS-13-9300:~/GitHub/SOQuestion$ pytest
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/eduardo/GitHub/SOQuestion, configfile: pyproject.toml
collected 1 item                                                                                    

test/test_logging.py::test_logging_with_multiprocessing PASSED                                [100%]

========================================= 1 passed in 0.02s =========================================
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, I determined that indeed `pytest`was the culprit responsible for not showing the child processes' logs in `sys.stdout`. With this, I found a GitHub issue from PyTest and used a [proposed solution](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3037#issuecomment-745050393) to achieve my requirements.

I extended the solution and added more tests to verify that the solution works for both `fork` and `spawn` multiprocessing contexts (testing if it works on UNIX and Windows systems). I have pushed the solution to the aforementioned GitHub repo ([commit](https://github.com/edavalosanaya/SOQuestion/commit/8fddcc6b84c85da380eea5462de2192a1b938630)). Here is the solution and the obtained output:

```py
import logging
import logging.handlers
import logging.config
import socket
from collections import deque
import pickle
import threading
import multiprocessing as mp

import pytest
from pytest_lazyfixture import lazy_fixture


LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": True,
    "formatters": {
        "standard": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",  # Default is stderr
        },
        "datagram": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "standard",
            "class": "logging.handlers.DatagramHandler",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 5555
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "": {
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": True,
        },
        "subprocess": {
            "handlers": ["datagram"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": True
        }
    },
}

# Setup the logging configuration
logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)

@pytest.fixture
def logreceiver():

    def listener():

        # Create server and logger to relay messages
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5555))
        logger = logging.getLogger("")

        # Continue listening until signaled to stop
        while True:

            # Listen for information
            data = s.recv(4096)
            if data == b"die":
                break

            # Dont forget to skip over the 32-bit length prepended
            logrec = pickle.loads(data[4:])
            rec = logging.LogRecord(
                name=logrec['name'],
                level=logrec['levelno'],
                pathname=logrec['pathname'],
                lineno=logrec['lineno'],
                msg=logrec['msg'],
                args=logrec['args'],
                exc_info=logrec['exc_info'],
                func=logrec['funcName'],

            )
            logger.handle(rec)

        # Safely shutdown socket
        s.close()

    # Start relaying thread
    receiver_thread = threading.Thread(target=listener)
    receiver_thread.start()

    yield

    # Shutting down thread
    t = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    t.sendto(b"die", ("127.0.0.1", 5555))
    receiver_thread.join()

def target_function():

    # Depending on the type of process, get the logger
    if 'Fork' in mp.current_process().name:
        logger = logging.getLogger("")
    elif "Spawn" in mp.current_process().name:
        logger = logging.getLogger("subprocess")
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Invalid multiprocessing spawn method.")

    # Test logging
    logger.info("Children Logging")


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "_logreceiver, ctx",
    [
        (lazy_fixture("logreceiver"), mp.get_context("spawn")),
        (lazy_fixture("logreceiver"), mp.get_context("fork")),

    ]
)
def test_something(_logreceiver, ctx):

    # Try different methods
    logger = logging.getLogger("")
    logger.info("Parent logging")

    ps = []
    for i in range(3):
        p = ctx.Process(target=target_function)
        p.start()
        ps.append(p)

    for p in ps:
        p.join()

    logger.info("Parent logging: end")
```

The approach uses a `Thread` listening to a UDP socket in the main process. Then the children processes send their logs to the UDP port. The `Thread` later relays the logs to the root logger. By avoiding using `QueueHandler` and other queue approaches, you don't have to manage queues in your subprocesses.

With this solution, I get the following test output:

```bash
======================================== test session starts ========================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.13, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/eduardo/GitHub/SOQuestion, configfile: pyproject.toml
plugins: lazy-fixture-0.6.3
collected 2 items                                                                                   

test/test_logging_working.py::test_something[logreceiver-ctx0] 
------------------------------------------- live log call -------------------------------------------
2022-11-06 10:48:51.748 [    INFO] Parent logging (test_logging_working.py:128)
2022-11-06 10:48:51.994 [    INFO] Children Logging (test_logging_working.py:113)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.005 [    INFO] Children Logging (test_logging_working.py:113)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.031 [    INFO] Children Logging (test_logging_working.py:113)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.079 [    INFO] Parent logging: end (test_logging_working.py:139)
PASSED                                                                                        [ 50%]
test/test_logging_working.py::test_something[logreceiver-ctx1] 
------------------------------------------- live log call -------------------------------------------
2022-11-06 10:48:52.084 [    INFO] Parent logging (test_logging_working.py:128)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.086 [    INFO] Children Logging (test_logging_working.py:113)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.088 [    INFO] Children Logging (test_logging_working.py:113)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.089 [    INFO] Children Logging (test_logging_working.py:113)
2022-11-06 10:48:52.091 [    INFO] Parent logging: end (test_logging_working.py:139)
PASSED                                                                                        [100%]

========================================= 2 passed in 0.37s =========================================

[Process exited 0]
```